# Interaction of a system of particles with a moving rigid-body object

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I tried to make a system of particles that would reflect from both active and passive rigid body objects (a plane is passive and a cube is an active rigid body object).

[image]

But when I try to run the animation, the particles bounce off the cube as if it is not moving but standing on the same spot while the cube falls down.

[image]

I also tried applying collision but that didn't help.
Is it possible to make particles bounce off a moving object in Blender?

[image] (Blender v. 3.5.0)